# White lines appear in texture

Tags: texturing

I tried to UV wrap a label to a bottle, but weird white lines appear on the UV wrap (lines in blue circles below). Original image does not have the white lines :

[image]

original image (cut):
[image]

UV Wrap printscreen:
[image]

weird polygon loops appear at upper and lower area:
[image]

Anyone can tell me what is the issue and how to fix it?

I am using Blender 2.81a, cycle.

Thanks!

Comment: it's because of the PNG format it compresses whatever is behind the transparency. if you want them to go away just setup your material accordingly

Comment: It looks like the original image isn't as tall as the label -- the regions you're talking about appear to be red bands above and below the image itself. That suggests you might be doing something interesting with the UV unwrapping -- can you show your UV map?

Comment: @Reese, you are right the issue the label did not cover the full area correctly. I wonder where the problem is? Added a printscreen for the UV map in the post above.

Comment: @Mobin, I checked the image, it is in jpg

Comment: Hello :). This looks like *Subdivision modifier* stretching the texture from adjacent faces. You can solve this by adding more loopcuts to the top and bottom edge.

Comment: @JachymMichal hey you are right again. After adding several loopcuts, the texture is now ok, without the upper and lower red bands. I also found that (in solid view) there are weird polygon loops (last image in the post above), these are the area where the red bands occured. So I can use these as reference for how many loopcuts to add and where to add.

Comment: Your Texture is being repeated. I forget exactly but I think you need to select "clip" or un select repeat.

Comment: @Dontwalk, I haven't tried this method, as it was already fixed by using suggestion by Jachym.

Comment: @JachymMichal, yes it does. Thanks :)